# For URDF files what alternatives to xml are there?

Tags: urdf, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I find that working directly with XML is unpleasant at best. What alternatives exist for creating URDF files either graphically or otherwise?

What I have found so far:

- [SimMechanics to
  URDF](https://github.com/robotology/simmechanics-to-urdf)
- [SW URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233557/for-urdf-files-what-alternatives-to-xml-are-there?/) by [hauptmech](https://answers.ros.org/users/1829/hauptmech/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2016-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried using python as a [data description language for URDF](https://github.com/hauptmech/odio_urdf)'s and it seems to work well. Less verbose and easier to read than xml. There is the added benifit that one does not need to use a preprocessor like xacro since the full capability of python is available.

---

Originally posted by [hauptmech](https://answers.ros.org/users/1829/hauptmech/) with karma: 71 on 2016-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-05-04**:
There is an ongoing discussion about this on the new mailing list: http://discourse.ros.org/c/robot-description-formats , and it's been discussed on the ros-users mailing list in the past.